# Asp.Net MVC 3 - Login page no css layout when securing site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, authorization

Ok... I don't get it. I just secured my asp.net mvc 3 app ( razor views ) with following code block in the web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

But when I do this, the Login page doesn't have the normal style anymore... it's just plain HTML without any css mockup.
So what do I have to 'allow' in the web.config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to allow scripts, styles ect

```
<location path="Styles">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="js">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Works now, only had to change the Styles to Content :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are denying access to anonymous users, it will no longer allow access to the folder containing your css file.

Add this in, where "Style" is the folder name containing your css file:

```
<location path="Style">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```